# How can I pull artifacts from TeamCity?

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, nant, teamcity, html-agility-pack

I would like to pull artifacts from teamcity.

I've been trying to use c# and the HtmlAgilityPack to goto the website and find the latest version and its artifacts. I'm currently stuck at the login, I think I just need to be sending Session Cookies out.

Am I going in the right direction, has anyone else tried this?

I realize that pushing files out with the build scripts is easy but I'd like to minimize changes to the Ant,NAnt files since I'm looking at scaling this to 100 apps.

**Edit:** this question looks promising [Getting HTML from a page behind a login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217/getting-html-from-a-page-behind-a-login)

**Edit:** this works now, I just need to write some code to parse it

```
WebClient ww = new WebClient();
ww.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
ww.DownloadString("http://yourteamcity.com/login.html");
ww.Headers.Add("Cookie",ww.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"]);

NameValueCollection post = new NameValueCollection();
post.Add("username", "name");
post.Add("remember","true");
post.Add("submitLogin", "Login");
post.Add("publicKey","long thing to intercept with fiddler");
post.Add("encryptedPassword","not giving you this");
post.Add("_", "");
byte[] values = ww.UploadValues("http://yourteamcity.com/loginSubmit.html", "POST",post);
string s = ww.DownloadString("http://yourteamcity.com/overview.html");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are simpler solutions, please read this: http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts