# Read XML into WSDL

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I'm making some calls via WSDL Webservice in my project .Net C # and I'm needing to see the XML Request and Response sends and received by WSDL, can anyone help me how can I read this information?

Comment: can you step thru the code and after you Invoke the WebService Method, that is hopefully if you have consumed it properly in your project, can you debug and do a QuickWatch on the variable to see the returned xml..

Comment: When you say "WSDL Web Service", you mean a .asmx service?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) on the server or client machine to capture the requests and responses.  Just start it up and it will monitor the http traffic on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SoapExtensions.  This method will simply write out log files containing all of the communications that the webservice performs. The XML will be there.

C# code:

```
// Define a SOAP Extension that traces the SOAP request and SOAP
// response for the XML Web service method the SOAP extension is
// applied to.

public class TraceExtension : SoapExtension 
{
    Stream oldStream;
    Stream newStream;
    string filename;

    // Save the Stream representing the SOAP request or SOAP response into
    // a local memory buffer.
    public override Stream ChainStream( Stream stream )
    {
        oldStream = stream;
        newStream = new MemoryStream();
        return newStream;
    }

    // When the SOAP extension is accessed for the first time, the XML Web
    // service method it is applied to is accessed to store the file
    // name passed in, using the corresponding SoapExtensionAttribute.   
    public override object GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute attribute) 
    {
        return ((TraceExtensionAttribute) attribute).Filename;
    }

    // The SOAP extension was configured to run using a configuration file
    // instead of an attribute applied to a specific XML Web service
    // method.
    public override object GetInitializer(Type WebServiceType) 
    {
        // Return a file name to log the trace information to, based on the
        // type.
        return "C:\\" + WebServiceType.FullName + ".log";    
    }

    // Receive the file name stored by GetInitializer and store it in a
    // member variable for this specific instance.
    public override void Initialize(object initializer) 
    {
        filename = (string) initializer;
    }

    //  If the SoapMessageStage is such that the SoapRequest or
    //  SoapResponse is still in the SOAP format to be sent or received,
    //  save it out to a file.
    public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message) 
    {
        switch (message.Stage) 
        {
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
                WriteOutput(message);
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
                WriteInput(message);
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("invalid stage");
        }
    }

    public void WriteOutput(SoapMessage message)
    {
        newStream.Position = 0;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append,
            FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);

        string soapString = (message is SoapServerMessage) ? "SoapResponse" : "SoapRequest";
        w.WriteLine("-----" + soapString + " at " + DateTime.Now);
        w.Flush();
        Copy(newStream, fs);
        w.Close();
        newStream.Position = 0;
        Copy(newStream, oldStream);
    }

    public void WriteInput(SoapMessage message)
    {
        Copy(oldStream, newStream);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append,
            FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);

        string soapString = (message is SoapServerMessage) ?
            "SoapRequest" : "SoapResponse";
        w.WriteLine("-----" + soapString + 
            " at " + DateTime.Now);
        w.Flush();
        newStream.Position = 0;
        Copy(newStream, fs);
        w.Close();
        newStream.Position = 0;
    }

    void Copy(Stream from, Stream to) 
    {
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(from);
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(to);
        writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        writer.Flush();
    }
}

// Create a SoapExtensionAttribute for the SOAP Extension that can be
// applied to an XML Web service method.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class TraceExtensionAttribute : SoapExtensionAttribute 
{

    private string filename = "c:\\log.txt";
    private int priority;

    public override Type ExtensionType 
    {
        get { return typeof(TraceExtension); }
    }

    public override int Priority 
    {
        get { return priority; }
        set { priority = value; }
    }

    public string Filename 
    {
        get 
        {
            return filename;
        }
        set 
        {
            filename = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In your web.config:

```
    <webServices>
        <soapExtensionTypes>
                <add type="ClassPath.To.Your.TraceExtension, Namespace.Containing.WebserviceCalls" priority="1" group="1"/>
        </soapExtensionTypes>
    </webServices>
```

The solution is described here:

[soap extension to log my webservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662492/soap-extension-to-log-my-webservices)

or

[How to trace ScriptService WebService requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020045/how-to-trace-scriptservice-webservice-requests)

or

http://blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx