# capturing HTML output in masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to capture the HTML output of an asp.net page in the master page's LoadComplete event. This is what I have:

```
public partial class MasterPage_MyBlogMainMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var PageURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

        HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        base.Render(hWriter);

        string PageResult = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the event doesn't seem to trigger. What do I need to change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work; if anyone comes to this page, this is how you do it. The problem is that `LoadComplete` event needs to be wired in the `Page_Load` method,  like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete);
}

protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ... now this works
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use `HttpHandler` (you can filter out not interesting pages in it also): [Capturing HTML generated from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386487/capturing-html-generated-from-asp-net)